# JavaFX Mac OS strange rendering

Tags: macos, javafx, render, java-8

**Hi all,**

I've got a simple question; I have a JavaFX based application that is dispayed correctly on Linux and Windows. But on my Mac Book Air late 2008 (core2duo) Mac OS 1.7.5 + JDK 8 I've got this render (a mix from my last web page I have seen, my app and some system's window's parts):

[image: Mac OS rendering error]

Have you encouter a similar problem ? Notice that eclipse is correctly working and other java apps also, only mine is looking like that. But there is no error shown in the Eclipse's console so I dot not know where to search, anyone has an idea ?

**Many thanks for reading me, Regards**

Comment: I have the same issue. Works fine on a PC, but has the same visual artifacts on an older Mac. Please reply if you find the cause/solution.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Do you have similar material/OS or your material/OS is greater than mine ? Even if I made some more tests (OpenJDK, early Sun JDK 8, Java 7 + JavaFX SDK) same result at the first time... I'll post if I have any updates on this issue.

Comment: I opened an issue with the JavaFX project: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36745.

Comment: In my own experimentation, it seems to be tied to the use of anti-aliasing in combination with a TableView that is wider than the sum of the width of its columns. Are you using these elements as well?

Comment: As a new information my app does not use the Anti aliasing that cause the problem for other people. I have to check the table column's sizes, I'll be back here when done...

Comment: My recommendation to you would be to file a bug report on the JIRA site that I linked above that includes system specs, code, and steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just post a comment on your Jira issue. Do you think I have to start another independant issue ?

Comment: My issue was fixed and closed, if I'm not mistaken, so it would be appropriate to file one separately, especially if your issue seems to be unrelated to mine.

Mine was (specifically) that text boxes on Mac were buggy when anti-aliasing was set to balanced. If that doesn't sound like you, then you should certainly file a separate report regardless of mine.